# iOS Application crashes from memory warning after returning from background, but not before?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory, memory-management

I have a strange situation. I have a fairly memory intense process (image processing) running, but I've worked out all the kinks and it runs just fine 99% of the time.

However, if I put the app in an inactive or background state, when returning and trying to run the same process I get memory warnings and then the app crashes.

I have used instruments to analyze the memory footprint in the two use cases and the memory footprint is exactly the same. However, in the case where I do not put the application into the background (or inactive) it doesn't give me any memory errors and completes fine. In the use case where it was put into the background (or inactive) I get memory errors and it crashes.

Does anybody have any information on this? I have been scouring the net / irc / stack over / apple docs trying to figure this out. Is apple (iOS) reducing the amount of memory my app is allowed to run with after I return from the background? Is there any way to prevent this? Or am I overlooking some other more simple solution?

(Note, there aren't memory leaks)

Comment: Please add error message to your Q.

Comment: There isnt an error message since it's a low memory error which causes the crash.

Comment: Do you do anything in your app delegate methods when entering or leaving the foreground / resigning / becoming active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright figured it out - iOS isn't doing anything stupid, it was of course the developer :) There was another component (ViewController) to my project which did some stuff when returning from the background, such as allocating memory. However, this view wasn't active so allocating the memory it needed proved to be useless. After cleaning up the code I didn't run into any memory errors.

Answer (score 2):

Just for check, while starting any background process it should be in autorelease pool. Background processes are running parallel with main thread. So while performing any task on background we should look at the memory. This is a common error often found for leak. Also operations that deals with UIKit always runs on main thread. So if you process any data through background & want to show it on UI then that will be loaded on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your app is receiving memory warnings whilst in the background, and your responses to this are different: for example, in the background all view controllers can have their contents unloaded when a memory warning is received, but in the foreground, your active view controller will not be unloaded. You could end up sending messages to deallocated instances, if say a view controller or one of its objects is set to be the delegate of some other process in your app which does not respond to low memory warnings.

Withou knowing the details of the crashes, which you really should include, and more about the structure of the app, this is my best guess.

Comment: I am not receiving any memory errors while in the background, and the views are all loaded when I resume the application. But when I hit "go" on my application to start processing the image, it crashes due to low memory, but only after returning from the background.

Comment: (I'm working w/Spongey on this as well)  Yea, the problem isn't that the app crashes while its in the background, it comes back to the foreground great, the problem is that then when we go on to use the app it crashes due to a low memory situation.  If we do the exact same behavior but w/out fast app switching away first it works fine, not a single warning.

Comment: So how does your app respond to low memory warnings? What do you get rid of?

Comment: Sorry we crossed comments there - you don't get any low memory warnings, just poof! Gone? I'm not sure if I can help you, then, I don't have any experience in that area.

Comment: @spongey in the simulator there is an option for simulate memory warning while running ur app. check wat does it shows at this situation..?